# Makefile recompile code after rebuild takes lot of time

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I use the Makefile to build the project.

After rebuild the project again without "make clean" before.

However, it takes a lot of time to rebuild it again.

It seems the syntax of the Makefile causing lots of time consuming.

But I am not familiar with Makefile syntax.

Could anyone points out the point if the statement incurs the lots of time 
consuming of the Makefile.

Here is the Makefile that I use:
https://github.com/cokeco/Makefile/blob/master/Makefile

Answer (score 0):

Use `make -d` output to debug why your targets are remade.